# Object that contains ArrayList

Tags: java, object, arraylist

I am doing a program to sell games. Now in my code it will show only the last review the customer writes, but instead I would like it to contain a list of all reviews the game got. I was thinking if it would be possible to have an `ArrayList` as a variable instead of the `String` review. Here is an example of how it looks like now.

```js
public class Game {
    private String gameName;
    private int gamePrice;
    private String gameReviews;

    public Game(String gameName, int gamePrice, String gameReviews) {
        this.gameName = gameName;
        this.gamePrice = gamePrice;
        this.gameReviews = gameReviews;
    }
}
```

and then if I want to create an object how it would look like to replace the old one I had?

```js
public class Games {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String gameN = "Name";
        int gameP = 10;
        String gameR = "Review";
        Game game = new Game(gameN, gameP,gameR);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use ArrayList instead of String.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Game {
    private String gameName;
    private int gamePrice;
    private ArrayList<String> gameReviews;

    public Game(String gameName, int gamePrice, ArrayList<String> gameReviews) {
        this.gameName = gameName;
        this.gamePrice = gamePrice;
        this.gameReviews = gameReviews;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String gameN = "Name";
        int gameP = 10;
        ArrayList<String> gameReviews =  new ArrayList<String>();
        
        gameReviews.add("Review 1");
        gameReviews.add("Review 2");
        gameReviews.add("Review 3");
        gameReviews.add("Review 4");
        Game game = new Game(gameN, gameP,gameReviews);
  }

}
```

Comment: Worked well, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If the relationship between your game and the reviews is one-to-many, the data type of your reviews can be `List<String>`

```java
public class Game {
    private String gameName;
    private int gamePrice;
    private List<String> gameReviews;

    public Game(String gameName, int gamePrice, List<String> gameReviews) {
        this.gameName = gameName;
        this.gamePrice = gamePrice;
        this.gameReviews = gameReviews;
    }

    public Game(String gameName, int gamePrice) {
        this.gameName = gameName;
        this.gamePrice = gamePrice;
        this.gameReviews = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void addGameReview (String gameReview) {
        this.gameReviews.add(gameReview);
    }
}
```

Then if you have the list of reviews at initialization you'd just pass it into the constructor:

```java
List<String> reviews = new ArrayList<>();
Game game = new Game(gameN, gameP, reviews);
```

Otherwise, you could have a constructor that initializes gameReviews to an empty `ArrayList`, and add the review after the initialization

```java
Game game = new Game(gameN, gameP);

game.addGameReview("This is a review of Game ...");
```